# How to make iframe content change according to the parent url

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display different pages in iframe, according to the parent url loaded. I have a mysql DB, which will be used for this purpose. I use the following code to call the appropriate link from the DB, but instead of showing that page, the iframe shows nothing (blank space).

This is the code, which I insert in my php files:

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http://';

$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

return $pageURL;
}

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
echo mysql_error();
mysql_select_db("db-name",$conn)or die(mysql_error());
$url=curpageURL();

$url=substr($url,0,strpos($url,'.',strpos($url,'?')));

$rs=mysql_query("select * from table-name where column1='".$url."'",$conn);
$affi=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo mysql_error();
echo '<iframe src="'. $affi['column2'].'" width="700" height="400"></iframe>';
```

As I said, this code shows only blank space and not the appropriate page. My site is running on SMF engine (Simple Machines Forum).

I hope someone can point me out what has to be changed in the code.
Thank you!

Comment: give please code of generated HTML page

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated MySQL extension anymore! It will be removed in near future. Switch to MySQLi or PDO - both using prepared statements.

Comment: on a more question-related note, "iframe content" has nothing to do with PHP. If you want to do something in an iframe based on the state of the page outside that iframe, you're going to have to first break through the iframe boundary; content inside an iframe is generally forbidden from accessing anything in the owner page, because of security restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but how to call outside page using this php code and without iframe?

Comment: @PetarIvanov - Is there code you're not showing that echos the html in which this iframe will reside?  Some browsers may be too strict to just show an orphaned iframe...

Comment: The above code is just one fragment which I insert through Ad-management system mod under all my articles.